# How to mangle function names used in event attributes with html-minifier-terser?

Tags: javascript, html, minify, terser, html-minifier

I am using the latest https://github.com/terser/html-minifier-terser `7.0.0` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier-terser)

The readme states

> Minify JavaScript in script elements and event attributes (uses Terser)

I am trying the following `minifyJS` options in attemt to "mangle" function names across the whole HTML:

```
{
    compress:{drop_console:true},
    mangle:{toplevel:true},
    nameCache:{}
}
```

However, while the script function is mangled to `n()`, the corresponding `<tag on...="javascriptfunction();">` attribute event handler does not get mangled, resulting in "Uncaught ReferenceError:  ... is not defined"

What am I missing?

- https://github.com/terser/terser
- https://terser.org/docs/cli-usage
- https://terser.org/docs/api-reference

Comment: The option `toplevel:true` (not the one in mangle) does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if the function definition comes first (i.e. *script* before *body*).
Workarounds:

- change the order
- attach function as [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) programmatically